# How to link to assets in laravel 6x

Tags: laravel

I just want to know how to link to assets in laravel 6x. In have already tried using > When I open my Developer tools I get 403 errors...and it tells me that access to my assets is forbidden.

I tried linking to assets in using the same syntax on Ubuntu 18.04 on laravel 5.8. I am running elementary os Juno.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/css/meanmenu.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/css/magnific-popup.css')}}">
```

Thats how I had formated my links to assets in the public folder.

2. GET

> http://127.0.0.2/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>   About:429 GET http://127.0.0.2/assets/js/ajax-mail.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>   About:430 GET http://127.0.0.2/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>   About:431 GET http://127.0.0.2/assets/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>   About:432 GET http://127.0.0.2/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>   About:434 GET http://127.0.0.2/assets/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
>   About:433 GET http://127.0.0.2/assets/js/plugins.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

I expected it to render my views but instead, the page shows only unstyled content. When I open my developer tools I get 403 errors next to my filed assets. Please refer to 2 up there

Answer (score 0):

```sh
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

This last operation will take several minutes to complete, but at the end it will create the `css/app.css` and `js/app.js` under the `public` directory.

Comment: Please add some description to your code explaining what is going on and why. This is good practice. If you don't, your answer is in risk of being deleted. It has already been flagged as low quality. Please also consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. Here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Asset](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-asset) function generates a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request.
 You can configure the asset URL host by setting the ASSET_URL variable in your .env file.
lets assume that you have just put your assets folder inside the public folder of your project and your are using localhost the ASSET_URL in .env file should look like this

```
ASSET_URL= http://localhost/MyprojectName/public
```

MyprojectName here you should replace with the name of your project or name of the folder that contain your project

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/css/meanmenu.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/css/magnific-popup.css')}}">
```

or you can use [LaravelMix](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix) to compile all your assets